# pure.CSS: responsive centered columns

Tags: yui-pure-css

With Bootstrap 3 there is an easy solution to center multiple columns as described here: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

Would it be possible to do this with Yahoo pure.CSS? And if yes, how?

For your suggestions and help many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a new CSS helper class to center the `.pure-u-*` items within a pure grid `div` (`.pure-g`):

```
.center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) is used because `.pure-g` uses flexbox. Adding the `.center` class to the `div` that defines the pure grid will then center the children:

```
<div class="pure-g center" style="background-color:blue">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3" style="background-color:teal">
      column 1
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3" style="background-color:red">
      column 2
    </div>
</div>
```

This [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNpQMJ) has two examples of centered responsive grids.

Comment: Great! Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.